# Xcode install fails at 95% under OS X El Capitan

Tags: xcode, macos

Tried to install Xcode for the first time. Tried 3 times now, same problem each time. After it reaches around 95% it fails, and I have to restart from scratch (2.5h). Going crazy.

Could it be because the computer goes into "rest-mode" while it installs?, i.e., black screen. Don't see what else it could be. Internet is fine, and I get no info apart from "Failed to install Xcode".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it following the instructions of the first answer to a similar question:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/97910/135650
You need to enable the debug menu for the App Store app and reset the application:

1. Open the terminal
2. Run the following command:
   `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true`
3. Relaunch the App Store app.
4. Choose the menu item Debug → Reset Application.

If you follow this instructions and still get any error I recommend you to check if you has at least 10GB of free space on disk before try again.

*Optionally, you can always download manually this or any other update from the following link:*

(you need to enter your Apple ID in order to be able to download)

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

or **even better** with this directly link(Xcode version 7.3):

https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3/Xcode_7.3.dmg