# Mac App Store failed downloads

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore

I've been having problems downloading several apps and updates from the Mac App Store.

One thing they have in common is that all of the problematic downloads are from Apple: Xcode, iTunes update, macOS Sierra beta, OS X El Capitan update.

My main suspicion: My ISP has a problem with Apple downloads. I also tried downloading Xcode from the Developers site and got a persistent "Invalid response" error.

Some quirks I noticed:

1. While downloading mac OS Sierra, a 2.15 GB download, every time I try, at the end of download, the progress report goes back and forth from 2.14 GB to 2.15 GB after ultimately failing. The same thing happened on another Mac downloading.
2. Trying to re-download Xcode or the iTunes update, the progress is reported an order of magnitude **faster** than my Internet connection, like 3/4 megabytes per second. That can't be true.
3. Xcode on the Purchased page doesn't have a DOWNLOAD button, rather, it has an INSTALL one.

What I have done so far:

1. Reset application from the Debug menu.
2. Found cache folder from Activity Monitor and deleted it.
3. Several reboots.
4. Logged out/in the App Store.
5. Checked for unfinished downloads.
6. Trying to solve using answers from: [Xcode failed to download. Use the Purchases page to try again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61646/xcode-failed-to-download-use-the-purchases-page-to-try-again?s=1%7C0.6028)

To finish, here's a dump from `/var/log/install.log`. I notice a few instances like:

> Failed post-download size check for package "iTunesAccess.pkg": expected 638270, got 638257

I couldn't test on another network yet, but will update when I do.

Any suggestions as to what I could be missing?

```
Sep 11 19:46:38 Precious softwareupdated[456]: 6 updates found:
    031-61467    | OS X El Capitan Update 10.11.6
    031-67169    | XProtectPlistConfigData 1.0
    031-72351    | Core Suggestions Configuration Data 762
    031-74368    | Chinese Word List Update 4.22
    031-77691    | Gatekeeper Configuration Data 100
    zzzz031-69279    | iTunes 12.4.3
Sep 11 19:46:44 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Ramped updates marked
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious installd[337]: PackageKit: Adding client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=312, uid=502 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeassetd)
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious storeassetd[312]: SUAppStoreUpdateController: authorize
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious installd[337]: PackageKit: Adding client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=456, uid=200 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdated)
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Cannot find local product zzzz031-69279 in index file
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious installd[337]: PackageKit: Adding client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=456, uid=200 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdated)
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious installd[337]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=456, uid=200 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdated)
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious storeassetd[312]: SUAppStoreUpdateController: disk space required for updates is: 1878615772
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious installd[337]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=456, uid=200 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdated)
Sep 11 19:46:56 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=312, uid=502, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeassetd)
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious storeassetd[312]: SUAppStoreUpdateController: start install session with zzzz031-69279
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious softwareupdated[456]: SUUpdateSession startUpdateForProducts:<SUProduct: zzzz031-69279> inForeground: YES staged: NO
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious softwareupdated[456]: SoftwareUpdate: Added foreground transaction [0x2] for iTunesX-12.4.3
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious softwareupdated[456]: SoftwareUpdate: starting download of zzzz031-69279 (iTunesX-12.4.3)
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Cannot find local product zzzz031-69279 in index file
Sep 11 19:46:56 Precious softwareupdated[456]: ContentLocator: No modified URL found
Sep 11 19:46:58 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Sep 11 19:46:58 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Finished downloading package iTunesAccess.pkg to file:///var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000s0000068/C/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate/CFNetworkDownload_WVtGVN.tmp (error (null)) from peer: 10.1.1.3
Sep 11 19:46:58 Precious softwareupdated[456]: zzzz031-69279: Failed post-download size check for package "iTunesAccess.pkg": expected 638270, got 638257
Sep 11 19:46:58 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Finished downloading package CoreADI.pkg to file:///var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000s0000068/C/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate/CFNetworkDownload_zq8OVW.tmp (error (null)) from peer: 10.1.1.3
Sep 11 19:46:58 Precious softwareupdated[456]: zzzz031-69279: Failed post-download size check for package "CoreADI.pkg": expected 1932602, got 1920316
Sep 11 19:47:10 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Finished downloading package CoreFP.pkg to file:///var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000s0000068/C/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate/CFNetworkDownload_8vHsxB.tmp (error (null)) from peer: 10.1.1.3
Sep 11 19:47:10 Precious softwareupdated[456]: zzzz031-69279: Failed post-download size check for package "CoreFP.pkg": expected 27581760, got 27581748
Sep 11 19:47:18 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Finished downloading package MobileDevice.pkg to file:///var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000s0000068/C/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate/CFNetworkDownload_QwCq9Y.tmp (error (null)) from peer: 10.1.1.3
Sep 11 19:47:18 Precious suhelperd[457]: Verifying package at path: /Library/Updates/zzzz031-69279/MobileDevice.pkg
Sep 11 19:47:18 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Host (null) isReachable = YES
Sep 11 19:47:23 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Retrying download for package: com.apple.pkg.MobileDevice
Sep 11 19:47:23 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Empty packageURL found for package com.apple.pkg.MobileDevice while retrying
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Finished downloading package iTunesX.pkg to file:///var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000s0000068/C/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate/CFNetworkDownload_yr4zTj.tmp (error (null)) from peer: 10.1.1.3
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious softwareupdated[456]: zzzz031-69279: Failed post-download size check for package "iTunesX.pkg": expected 144915862, got 144919952
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious softwareupdated[456]: No more tasks - invalidating session now
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious softwareupdated[456]: SULocalProduct: zzzz031-69279 is not completely downloaded.  Package with identifier com.apple.pkg.iTunesX not found:
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious softwareupdated[456]: SoftwareUpdate: Invalid or incomplete local product zzzz031-69279
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Removing local product after found to be incomplete
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Removed local product for zzzz031-69279 (1)
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious softwareupdated[456]: Stopping transaction with ID [0x2]
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious softwareupdated[456]: SoftwareUpdate: Removed foreground transaction [0x2]
Sep 11 19:47:28 Precious storeassetd[312]: SUAppStoreUpdateController: status for zzzz031-69279: zzzz031-69279 (a=0x3): install error (234125311 of 237486812) 49.3% -1.0s (error: Error Domain=SUErrorDomain Code=301 "The update has been deleted since being downloaded from the Apple Software Update server." UserInfo={SUErrorUpdateTitle=iTunes, SUErrorUpdateProductKey=zzzz031-69279, NSLocalizedDescription=The update has been deleted since being downloaded from the Apple Software Update server.})
```

EDIT: I have finally been able to test it on another network, and in fact this is related to my ISP failing to connect me to Apple's servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a network related issue. I have been able to download the file correctly when connected through another ISP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a couple of months ago - after some digging through the vast forums on the internet, I found three commands that basically restored permissions to the App Store:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared
sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared
sudo chmod -R 1777 /Users/Shared
```

Execute each of these in Terminal (Utilities folder on the Mac) and restart the computer. Since then, I never had that problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did what you mentioned, but in my case it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an app that would vanish from my Applications folder immediately after it had finished being downloaded.

Deleting the app's receipts from `/private/var/db/receipts` and `/Library/Receipts` solved it for me.

Comment: I did as you mentioned, unfortunately that's not what's causing my issue. I'm starting to suspect something spiritual related rather than software related at this point.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(